# Summing a filtered column in DataTables

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm trying to sum the results of filtered columns in DataTables. I've viewed the questions asked on their website and folks have had success using [this method](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2053/fnfootercallback-sum-column-after-filter).

However, similar code for me produces 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function."

```js
data = table._('td:nth-child(10)', {"filter": "applied"});
```

where 'table' is:

```js
var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
// my initialization data
});
```

Comment: I found this helpful: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`_` (the underscore function) seems to be deprecated in dataTables 1.10.x. In theory it should work with `$('#dataTable').dataTable()` (the old constructor) but this does not give the expected result (as least not for me).

But see this -> **http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/sum()**

```js
jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'sum()', function () {
    return this.flatten().reduce( function ( a, b ) {
        return (a*1) + (b*1); // cast values in-case they are strings
    });
});

var table = $("#example").DataTable();

$("#example").on('search.dt', function() {
    console.log(table.column( 0, {page:'current'} ).data().sum() );
});
```

would give the same functionality in dataTables 1.10.x as you want in the question header.

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/6qLwkwud/**

`table.column( 0, {"filter": "applied"} ).data().sum()` works perfectly well also.

Comment: For anyone else referencing this do check out https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier which provides more info incase you still don't get the applied data set.