# Jquery Datatable Calculate Sum in footer while Searching :

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

**Fiddle**:  http://jsfiddle.net/6qLwkwud/43/

I want to add a total on filtered records while searching on a datatable.

Adding the initial total to the footer was quite easy but I am facing issues while recalculating sum in `search.dt` event.

From the logs I see this error :

> TypeError: table.api is not a function

I think the `this` reference in `initComplete` works for me initially.
Now How do I get this reference inside  `search.dt` event ?

**Note** : I have gone through this [Summing a filtered column in DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307622/summing-a-filtered-column-in-datatables).
but it does not solve my purpose as I am using classes to denote my columns where I want to apply. & in my table I don't know how many columns would have that attribute.

**HTML :**

```
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr><th class="sum">a column</th>
        <th class="sum">b column</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td >10</td> <td>15</td></tr>
        <tr><td>10</td> <td>18</td></tr>
        <tr><td>20</td> <td>20</td></tr>
        <tr><td>20</td> <td>25</td></tr>
        <tr><td>30</td> <td>28</td></tr>
        <tr><td>30</td> <td>30</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>

      </th>
      <th class="Int">

      </th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

**Script :**

```
var table = $("#example").DataTable({
 "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
 var api = this.api();
 CalculateTableSummary(this);
}
});

$("#example").on('search.dt', function() {
    CalculateTableSummary(table);  
});



function CalculateTableSummary(table) {
    try {

        var intVal = function (i) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
        };

        var api = table.api();
        api.columns(".sum").eq(0).each(function (index) {
            var column = api.column(index);

            var sum = column
               .data()
               .reduce(function (a, b) {
                   //return parseInt(a, 10) + parseInt(b, 10);
                   return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
               }, 0);



            if ($(column.footer()).hasClass("Int")) {
                $(column.footer()).html('' + sum.toFixed(0));
            } else {
                $(column.footer()).html('' + sum.toFixed(2));
            }

        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error in CalculateTableSummary');
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: You have initialised with `DataTable()` so `var api = table.api()` is meaningless in `CalculateTableSummary`. the passed `table` **is** the `api`! It only makes sense if you have initialised with `dataTable()` ...

Comment: @davidkonrad I had expected that but somehow it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it by adding a `footerCallbackFunction` & passing `{page:'current'}` to the sum method.

http://jsfiddle.net/ubh6crqu/2/

```
var table = $("#example").DataTable({
 "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
 var api = this.api();
 CalculateTableSummary(this);
},
        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {

            var api = this.api(), data;  
     CalculateTableSummary(this);
     return ;       
            }
});



function CalculateTableSummary(table) {
    try {

        var intVal = function (i) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
        };

        var api = table.api();
        api.columns(".sum").eq(0).each(function (index) {
            var column = api.column(index,{page:'current'});

            var sum = column
               .data()
               .reduce(function (a, b) {
                   //return parseInt(a, 10) + parseInt(b, 10);
                   return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
               }, 0);


console.log(sum);

            if ($(column.footer()).hasClass("Int")) {
                $(column.footer()).html('' + sum.toFixed(0));
            } else {
                $(column.footer()).html('' + sum.toFixed(2));
            }

        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error in CalculateTableSummary');
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var table = $().Datatable({
  ...
  initComplete: function () {
    CalculateTableSummary(this.api());
  }
  ...
});

function CalculateTableSummary(api) {
  ...
  //var api = table.api();
  ...
}
```

Comment: initial one is already working. I want to change the sum based on the rows filtered.

Comment: var sum = column
               .rows(function (index, value, dom) {
             return $(dom).is(':visible')
            })
               .data()
               .reduce(function (a, b) {
                   return a + intVal(b[index]);
               }, 0);